# Address Translation for a page not in RAM but in disk

Tags: c, linux

I understand that to locate a page in RAM we make use of the page table for the address translation. My confusion is what if the page is not in RAM and needs to be swapped from disk. How is the address translation done in that case?

Comment: The page is first loaded to RAM, then address can be translated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a big picture of that process:

- CPU sends a virtual address to MMU (Memory Management Unit)
- MMU tries to fetch a page table entry from memory/cache
- MMU finds out that page is invalid (e.g. valid bit = 0)
- MMU throws an exception, page fault handler is invoked
- handler might save to disk the page that is going to be overwritten
- handler brings up wanted physical address to memory in place of the previously identified victim
- page table entries are updated (in order to reflect a changes that were done)
- instructions from CPU are re-executed
- now MMU is able to find a PTE with valid bit equal to 1

Here's also a pretty nice explanation of it : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cao/cs537/lecture17.txt